Embeding LVC player on a gtk3 widget under wayland
I use libvlc 3.0.18 in a gtk3.0 APP to play videos inside a widget. Under X11 everything is fine, but if I switch to Wayland, VLC creates a popup window to play the video.
After some debugging I found that under Wayland the following code fails:
    libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow(media_player, GDK_WINDOW_XID(gtk_widget_get_window(widget)));

with GDK_WINDOW_XID(gtk_widget_get_window(widget)) returning NULL.
What is the proper way to replace the above piece of code to make the app work under Wayland????
Thanks in advance.

LibVLC 3.x does not yet support Wayland. LibVLC 4.x likely will.
You could try something like Xwayland in the meantime https://wayland.freedesktop.org/xserver.html
